# Is there any way to copy/clone an existing item to create a completely new item using a resource pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

In Minecraft, I want to clone an item in a resource pack to create a new item or at least make different variants of the same item. Say for example I wanted two diamond helmets that are each a different color. Is this possible? How do I accomplish this?